# How to connect Lenovo laptop to external monitor?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I have windows 10 x64 on Lenovo laptop g500 series.

The screen is not working and just showing white screen.

As in below screen.

[image]

Earlier used to work if I keep my laptop screen in a particular angle, now completely gone.

Once in a while it will show and can connect to monitor after login to windows. But need to connect from boot setup screen itself, so even if it is completely damaged later, I can use other monitors.

I tried connecting external monitor but it is showing as not detected.

Tried on both Dell and samsung monitor with both vga and HDMI cable.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your laptop have a **function key** for external displays? Did you try it? Alternatively, you could try pressing **Win+P**

Comment: Closing the laptop lid after connecting any external monitor should work, whether or not you use a hotkey or "enable" the external display. If that isn't working, its likely your computer has other serious hardware issues.

Comment: The function key combo will be Fn+F10, or just F10 if your system defaults to the utility keys first.

Comment: @svin83 it would be helpful if you read the question completely.

Comment: @music2myear I am asking how to and you replied as what to. That enable option not there in bios also. Why would I create a question if it is that simple. And I didn't ask how to open bios, please read the question completely

Comment: And thanks for your reply first of all. Lis closing is not enabling the monitor

Comment: There's not usually an option in the BIOS these days. Like I said, if closing the lid doesn't work to send the display externally, your computer has other significant hardware faults.